# Rails - Speeding up my Items#Index action with database queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, model-view-controller

I noticed as I have been moving along with developing my app and creating lots of items/listing the load times are getting much longer. I suspect it's the way my action in the controller is querying the database. The view uses erb to perform @item.each do and checks if @item.orders.any? and will display only the items without orders. The code basically has to go through every single item in the database perform this check and then render the results, which I suspect will be a nightmare with over 100+ items.

Is there a smarter way to do this?

This is is simple marketplace application where buyers and sellers can perform business. A seller lists an item and it shows up on the Items#Index page along with the other items. A buyer click on it and clicks buy which brings them to an order page which they can then check out with PayPal. After PayPal IPN is received the order is committed to the database.

Here is the code:

## Excerpt from the server logs when loading the index action

```
Started GET "/" for 73.110.34.200 at 2017-07-31 13:19:38 -0500
Cannot render console from 73.110.34.200! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by ItemsController#index as */*
  Rendering items/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Item Load (10.3ms)  SELECT "items".* FROM "items" ORDER BY "items"."created_at" DESC, created_at DESC
  Order Exists (1.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."item_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["item_id", 19], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Order Exists (3.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."item_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["item_id", 18], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Order Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."item_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["item_id", 17], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Order Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."item_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["item_id", 16], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Order Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."item_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["item_id", 15], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Order Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."item_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["item_id", 14], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Order Exists (0.8ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."item_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["item_id", 13], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Order Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."item_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["item_id", 12], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Order Exists (0.8ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."item_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["item_id", 11], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Order Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."item_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["item_id", 10], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Order Exists (0.8ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."item_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["item_id", 9], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Order Exists (3.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."item_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["item_id", 8], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Order Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."item_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["item_id", 7], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Order Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."item_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["item_id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Order Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."item_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["item_id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Order Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."item_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["item_id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Order Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."item_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["item_id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Order Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."item_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["item_id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Order Exists (0.8ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."item_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["item_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered items/index.html.erb within layouts/application (226.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_rails_default.html.erb (194.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (20.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (1.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 666ms (Views: 564.1ms | ActiveRecord: 28.3ms)
```

## ItemsController

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :deny_access
  rescue_from ActionView::MissingTemplate, with: :template_not_found


  def garage
    @items = current_user.items
  end

  def show
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  end

  # GET /items
  # GET /items.json
  def index
    @items = Item.all
    if params[:search]
      @items = Item.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
    else
      @items = Item.all.order("created_at DESC")
    end
  end

  # GET /items/new
  def new
    @item = current_user.items.build
  end

  # GET /items/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /items
  # POST /items.json
  def create
    @item = current_user.items.build(item_params)
    @item.username = current_user.username

    respond_to do |format|
      if @item.save
        format.html { redirect_to @item, notice: 'Item was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @item }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /items/1
  # PATCH/PUT /items/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @item.update(item_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @item, notice: 'Item was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @item }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /items/1
  # DELETE /items/1.json
  def destroy
    @item.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to items_url, notice: 'Item was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def favorite
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    type = params[:type]
    if type == "favorite"
      current_user.favorites << @item
      redirect_to :back

    elsif type == "unfavorite"
      current_user.favorites.delete(@item)
      redirect_to :back

    else
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end

  def favorites
    @items = current_user.favorites
  end

  def deny_access
    redirect_to :back
  rescue ActionController::RedirectBackError
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def template_not_found
    redirect_to :back
  rescue ActionView::MissingTemplate
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_item
      @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def item_params
      params.require(:item).permit(:title, :content, :filepicker_url, :price, :shipping_price, :paypal_email)
    end
end
```

## Items#Index View

```
<div class="row">
  <%= form_tag(items_path, :method => "get") do %>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
      <div class="input-group">
        <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search items...", class: "form-control" %>
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil, class: "btn btn-default btn-block" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
<br>

<% if @items.blank? %>
  <h4>There are no items containing the term <%= params[:search] %>.</h4>
<% end %>

<h1>Items</h1>
      <% @items.each do |item| %>
      <% if item.orders.any? %>
        <% else %>
          <div class="col-md-3">
              <%= link_to(filepicker_image_tag(item.filepicker_url.split(",").last, w: 200, h: 200, fit: 'crop'), item) %><br>
              <p class="bold"><%= item.title %><br></p>
              <p><%= link_to number_to_currency(item.price), item %></p>
              <p class="small"><%= time_ago_in_words(item.created_at) %> ago</p>
          </div> 
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
<br>
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `includes` to eager load the association.

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    if params[:search]
      @items = Item.search(params[:search]).includes(:orders).order("created_at DESC")
    else
      @items = Item.all.includes(:orders).order("created_at DESC")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! This works well. The server log is no longer displaying every item query and performs and Order Load instead of Order Exists. Average load time has dropped by about 25 ms.

Comment: @bloodrunner great! as the SO way to say thanks, if you're satisfied with the answer can you please accept it?